# Marklogic Content Processing Framework (CPF) is not triggered when loaded the documents with MarkLogic Content Pump (MLCP))

Tags: marklogic

I am loading the data from a pipe delimited file and i am storing them as XML documents as part of ingestion using MLCP. I have my CPF pipelines based on the state(initial), and the namespace and root element condition.

The CPF framework is not getting triggered when i load the documents using MLCP, but if i deploy  the test content using Roxy(ml dev deploy content) which are already in XML, the transformation is happening successfully.

I noticed the state of the document is in initial when loading through Roxy, where are the state of the document is in created state when loading through MLCP.

So i have changed the pipeline state transition to trigger when the document is in created state. Even then i dont see CPF is triggered when documents are created as MLCP process

Please need help to fix the issue

MLCP Options, CPF Config and Pipeline XML file -- [https://gist.github.com/guru2228)

Comment: Can you please share the mlcp command line, your cpf config, and a snippet of your xml?

Comment: pipeline-config.xml -- https://gist.github.com/guru2228/a74ff999abf5d87b75df

Comment: demographic-pipeline.xml --- https://gist.github.com/guru2228/42dfeef370b19ebf3422

Comment: ingest-options file -- https://gist.github.com/guru2228/1cfd4f211a507b4144f9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a permissions problem, or it could be that you need to configure a [CPF Restart Trigger](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api/cpf#id_20565).

When CPF gets set up, that creates a set of triggers. In the Admin UI (port 8001), you can see the resulting triggers by viewing the configuration of your target database (say, Documents) and then clicking Triggers in the display on the left. You should see a list that includes cpf:restart. Click that one and check the "user" option.

If there was no cpf:restart, then it sounds like CPF didn't get set up correctly (you're using Roxy; did you run "[ml deploy cpf](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/wiki/Working-with-CPF#deploying)"?).

If cpf:restart was there, does the user have permissions to read and update the documents that it should be working with?

Comment: Yes there was the permission problem. The user account that loaded the documents using MLCP has different privileges than the CPF user.
After correcting the roles, now it is working. Thanks for the input